# Intramolecular hydrazide condensation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

Say I have acetohydrazide ($\ce{CH3CONHNH2}$).

Is it possible, that when I add an acid, an intramolecular condensation reaction occurs, forming the cyclic compound 3-methyl-1⁠*H*-diazirine:

[image: 3-methyl-1H-diazirine]

Furthermore, in general, the mechanism of such a reaction is nucleophilic substitution, right?

Comment: Nope, no chance. Three-atomic rings are extremely strained, even more so with double bonds in the ring, so they form only in reactions with extremely high-energetic particles, such as carbenes.

Comment: But if we, for a second, discount the strain factor, such a reaction will be possible right?

Comment: Your starting material is a hydrazide. Where is the semicarbazone?

Comment: @DhananjayGupta The usual synthesis of imidazole (see wiki for the structure) involves condensation of o-phenylenediamine with formic acid. But you can't dismiss strain factor here.

Comment: To avoid the strain, it would be much more likely for an intermolecular condensation to occur.

Comment: The concept of 'discount the strain factor' is nonsensical.  Furthermore, hydrazides are relatively resistant to nucleophilic addition-elimination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reaction product is a double bond isomer of a **diazirine**.

Halogene-substituted derivatives of the latter are typically prepared via oxidation of amidines with hypochlorites (*Graham* oxidation).

Heating your hydrazide in an aqueous solution of a mineral acid will only turn it to the corresponding carboxylic acid.